# KotOR always crashes mid game

Tags: windows-7, crash, nvidia-graphics-card, gaming

So I've recently reinstalled the first Knights of the Old Republic (not to be confused with The Old Republic), on PC. Now the last time I played this game on PC was when I was running Windows XP, and it ran perfectly fine.

KotOR 2 works fine on my machine, however the first one always crashes on the same PC. It always crashes on the Endar Spire, either when turning the camera around in the first hallway with the two sith and the dead republic soldier, or when selecting a menu item/rotating the camera in the next two hallways. I have tried enabling/disabling VSync, soft shadows, grass, buffer effects, AA, AF, compatibility mode for Win2000/XPSP2/XPSP3, in windowed mode, both 800x600 and 1024x768, hardware mouse enabled and disabled, Nvidia drivers 296 and 375, and every combination that those settings will allow. I'm at my wit's end and annoyed by the inconsistency given the fact that KoTOR 2, which uses the same engine, works fine.

My specs are below:

```
System:
CPU: i3-4330 3.5GHz.
GPU: Quadro 410 512MB.
RAM: 8GB.
VID: 1360x768 Native via DVI-D.
OS : Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

GPU Support:
Driver : 375.63.
DirectX: 12.0.
OpenGL : 4.5.
Shader : 5.0.
```

And here is the crash log in case it helps:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: swkotor.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.3.0
  Application Timestamp:    00000000
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_be9b
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   00000000
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 07d72b04
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: be9b
  Additional Information 2: be9bf493184e8a1cc6dbc11c84c53984
  Additional Information 3: a099
  Additional Information 4: a0997196efb56d84f9f4ce5a43974546
```

Comment: I'm playing the original PC-CD version.

Comment: Never mind; The patch is for the sequel; Your still looking at an incompatibility problem though

Comment: @Ramhound I am aware of that, what I am wondering if there is any way to fix it, or alternatively any way to virtualize the game so that I can still play it. I have ample HDD space, however my windows XP install disc crashes when I attempt to install it on this PC so I can't make a KotOR specific install.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on getting the original version to work and just installed a copy from GOG. Now I've been able to get about 6 hours into the game with no crashes whereas before I was only able to make it 5-20 minutes in because it kept crashing whenever heavy lighting, particle, or buffer effects were invoked. If I had to guess I would assume it is because the GOG version has had engine modifications to make it more compatible with the way newer graphics cards go about invoking DirectX's object and frame buffer effects. Again this is only a guess but I do know I haven't had another crash since I migrated my saves over to the new installation so I suppose it sadly just isn't possible to get the original version of KotOR working on setups that combine Win7+ and DirectX12 graphics cards. A shame given how good of a game this is that the older copies have to be relegated to use on older machines.